# Get words of a pastebin and turn them into a keyword list

Tags: python

for example I have a raw pastebin: https://pastebin.com/raw/YsgHMTkZ
like:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
word6
...
```

And I'd just like to put them in a variable like this:

**keyword_name = ["word1","word2","word3","word4","word5","word6","..."]**

Thank you, have a good day.

Comment: Copy paste and edit it.

Comment: check `requests` package to retrieve the content over http, then parse it as a regular string

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including code for what you've tried so far based on your own research, with a specific question regarding how your current output is different than your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a `GET` request with `requests`, retrieve the contents, split them by spaces. And then `split` will already return a list for you.

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/YsgHMTkZ')
result = resp.text.split()
print(result)
# ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'word6', '...']
```

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what I wanted <3

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas read_csv() which allows url input as well.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"https://pastebin.com/raw/YsgHMTkZ", header=None)
lst = df.iloc[:,0].to_list()
```